# How can I get the exact URLs/requests that a program is trying to connect to?

Tags: macos, network, security, firewall, monitoring

I currently use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to control network traffic on my Macbook Pro, and see what my apps are connecting to.

Unfortunately, Little Snitch only shows you the hostname that an app is connecting to. Is there a tool which will show you the full URL of the requests that apps are making? Even better if you can view the headers.

Comment: Have you been able to go as far as to see when there is a post and even see when a json file is received from a url?

Comment: I want to be able to login with my valid credentials and make requests to a website I have access to using my own code instead of their website.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The most full featured way to peek into web traffic is to install and configure your system to use a web proxy.

The [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) proxy (and `mitmdump` tool) is mature, reliable and well documented so I would start there unless you have another that meets your specific needs.

Also, widely used, superbly documented and well regarded is [Charles Proxy](https://charlesproxy.com)

[image: Image from mitmproxy.org/images/mitmproxy.png]

Comment: This is an excellent solution and it saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: mitmproxy is good if you're happy to manually set the proxy server (e.g. in your browser settings). But if you want to see **every** HTTP request coming from your local machine (even not from a browser), [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is the way to go, with a display filter of `http`. It's installer automatically gets the OS permissions that it needs to listen, whereas `mitmproxy` doesn't, and it's tricky to get working.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like you need a packet sniffer.

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will log and do full disassembly on all traffic going through your network interface.

[image]

In other words, it will not just show you the full URLs of each request, but it will let you look inside all the packets, so you can see the headers and content too (except in SSL connections, as they are encrypted).

It works on just about every platform out there, including Macs.

Comment: How do you see the URLs? There's so much traffic that I can't see the URLs.

Comment: @daviesgeek - Add a filter for `GET` requests. That will let you just see the requests for HTTP requests. Alternatively, you can filter for whatever type of traffic you are looking for, if you're not just looking for HTTP. It should also be able to filter for DNS requests.

Comment: Also, you're going to want to turn off anything else running in the background, if you can. Since wireshark shows you everything, reducing the volume of traffic you're not interested in helps tremendously.

Comment: This answer has a good explainer on filtering so you only see HTTP requests, and remove all the noise of lower-level TCP, IP, UDP packets, etc: https://serverfault.com/questions/96272/how-to-filter-http-traffic-in-wireshark

Answer (score 6):

I recommend `ProxyMan`. It's hands down the best client in this space IMO. The free tier is amazing for most non-pro users. They also have a mobile app. https://proxyman.io . I love this app!

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a free tier any more - $69 as of March 2023.

Comment: @stwr667 It's a bit hidden. If you go here: https://proxyman.io/pricing and see the section "What are the differences between the Free and Premium versions?" you'll see what the difference is for the free and premium tier. It's a brilliant app.

Comment: Oh gee, that is hidden! So to be clear, is the trial time-limited or not? Even the wording on that looks intentionally unclear. It's clear that it's feature-limited.

Comment: @stwr667 the limits are listed in the explanation on the website. there is no trial limit that I'm aware of. it's a very generous free tier. if you're making money using a tool like this it's considered bad form to not contribute to the developer.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it won't give you the full URL, if you're a fan of the command line, then [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) also comes in quite handy and shows you both incoming and outgoing hosts, port numbers (names for well known ports) and cumulative totals for each - as well as live updating "graphs" on the command line :-)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### [HandsOff!](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/)

is very similar to Little Snitch. I've explained differences in an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34159/13414).

The network monitor shows hostnames, but it will distinguish them if they have *different IPs*.  Via right-click you can get the specific IP address - you don't get to see the full URL request. But the IP address is more specific anyway.

[image]

The developers are open to feature requests. You might see such a feature added in the future.

Comment: In the picture you see several entries for `api.tweetdeck.com` (in total it's about a dozen). Each IP has it's own entry.

Answer (score 0):

A newer application which is available now is [Proxie](https://proxie.app/).

Compared to Charles Proxy, which is $50, Proxie is only $10. (Charles Proxy does have a demo available, and is an excellent app, but Proxie has worked very well for me.)

You can use Proxie to see both **http** and **https** URLs. There is a fairly simple process required to setup the **https** monitoring (you need to generate and install a certificate), but it only has to be done once, and the instructions are quite straight-forward.

I believe that this is the easiest solution to the OP’s question.

Comment: Note that Proxie no longer appears to be available for purchase from the App Store. There is a trial download available from the website, but it likely is not being actively developed going forward.