# Is there a way to track my look ups in the OSX dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary, look-up

I am a non-english native speaker and therefore use the OSX's built-in look up service ([three-finger tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507457/how-can-i-override-the-3-finger-tap-behavior-in-a-nstextview) and [`cmd+L` in the spotlight search field](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11266)) quite a lot.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep track of or record the words I have looked up? (Applescript perhaps?)

*EDIT:* When I three-finger tab it also gives me definitions from wikipedia. Could I utilise this, i.e. [track the requests Dictionary.app sends to wikipedia.org](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40468/how-can-i-get-the-exact-urls-requests-that-a-program-is-trying-to-connect-to), to track which words I look up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with the normal three-finger tap, but if you make an Automator service with some Applescript, you can trigger it on a keyboard shortcut. (Note: This shows a full dictionary window, not a nice popover. I don't think there's a way to do it like that.)

To make this service, open Automator.app, in the `/Applications/` folder.

Choose Service.
[image: Service selected in the Automator startup sheet]

Then, in the Library on the left, search for AppleScript, and drag Run Applescript over.

Here's the script to paste in.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set logPath to "Desktop/words.txt"
    --You can change the path in quotes
    --to the file you want to store the
    --words you look up.

    set lookUpWord to quoted form of (input as string)
    --This sets the word to the selected text, from input.

    do shell script "cd; echo " & lookUpWord & " >> " & quoted form of logPath
    --This appends the word to the log file.

    do shell script "open dict://" & lookUpWord
    --This opens the word in Dictionary.

    return input
end run
```

Click the hammer to compile. It should look like this:
[image]

The last thing to do is assign a keyboard shortcut.
Save the workflow (I called mine "look up"), and open System Preferences.
Go to Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services.

Select your service (It should be under Text), then click "add shortcut" and type the shortcut you'll be using to trigger it.
[image]
I like to use <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>control ^</kbd> and a letter, because those are almost guaranteed not to be already in use by an application.

That should work! Just select a word by double-clicking, then type your keyboard shortcut to use it.

Comment: Does this work in Yosemite? It seems to work in other applications but not Safari or Chrome. Anyone with success?

Comment: @Kar did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm afraid not.