# Apple Bug Report (Apple's Response Time?)

Tags: xcode, bug

I did a bug report because of this Xcode Situation ( [Xcode.app gets scanned by socketfilterfw (OS X Firewall) at every launch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187924/xcode-app-gets-scanned-by-socketfilterfw-os-x-firewall-at-every-launch) ).

I wonder about the time *Apple* usually needs to respond.

Weeks, Months? I really have no clue.
If you know more (from your experience) please tell me.

Comment: Looking over the 15 bugs I've reported since 2005, I've never received a response from bugreport.apple.com. If the bug you're reporting is a common one, and thus Apple has many reports already, you'll never get a response.

Comment: Thanks. Ah ok, I see. I thought they will somehow send me a mail lol silly me. But the status changed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no easy way to tell how/when/if Apple acts on your bug report. I have filed quite a few bug reports during the last years. Some still seem to be unchanged since I created them, some got closed silently and there is only one where I ever got notified that the fix would be in the next OS X release.

So basically you filed the report, now just ignore it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you should file your bug on [Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/), that is a community maintain website who tries to keep as much reports public. A radar basically contains just the same information you report to Apple.

Note that, usually OSX/iOS developers ask for help regarding concrete radars, this is because "we suppose/believe" that if lots of people reports the same bug, it will be fixed soon. It's a common practice to report a bug on Apple bug tracker by just copying the radar report.

Answer (score 1):

If you've developer account, you can try to report the bug at [ Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with specific details of reproducing the issue. The time depends how on its *Rank* and whether the bug was described accurately.

If it's major issue, I believe it'll get the response fairly quickly.